# Ugly font rendering (ubuntu 12, overrides system settings)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, fonts, linux, ubuntu

Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 12 renders fonts very poorly. 
Text is readable, but it makes it very hard to concentrate on programming.

Since smoothing on Ubuntu on low DPI screens isn't very good either, I turned it off and have been using fonts that are friendly without smoothing (e.g. Courier New). Mathematica completely ignores this fact and smoothes them anyway (in some proprietary way that seems to be different from the way how ubuntu smoothes them (when smoothing is system-wide enabled)).

Is there any option how to modify/disable this behavior ?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot showing your problem?

Comment: I'm having [a similar problem on OS X](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37732/37). It seems that Mathematica just ignores what's going on in the system.