# Why are fonts in my notebooks grainy after transferring to a new machine?

Tags: notebooks, fonts, mac-os-x, antialiasing

After transferring *Mathematica* (and successfully transferring my license) to a new machine (a Retina MacBook Pro) all the fonts in my documents look jagged:

[image]

How do I get *Mathematica* to show smooth fonts that take advantage of the Retina display?

---

For comparison, this is how sharp fonts are in a well-behaved application:

[image]

Comment: Related (maybe) http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54906

Comment: From the same thread _"An alternative to waiting for all your apps to update to Retina, is to use the native 2880x1800 resolution. Apps that are not updated will look fine, but text will look small. Most of the apps that have a problem with retina have zoom though so you can just zoom their display area. "_

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I'd say that it's unbelievable, but it's not. Typical Wolfram.